# Unwanted Script being added to all HTML pages in all browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, virus, html

I don't know why but this has been happening for a while now:

In every browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE) there is always a script attached at the end of the code.

That's the script:

```
http://cupons.dantis.com.br/api/app/landing.php?app=QUMtMjItMEItQkQtODAtQUQ=&aff=999999&partner=999999
```

It's an adware or something, I blocked the domain `coupons.dantis.com.br` on my hosts file only so the php script won't run and gather my personal info.

But the script is always there anyways, I have tried unninstalling the browsers and the extensions, I have removed many programs that seemed suspicious, nothing.

I ran Junkware Removal Tool, AdwCleaner, antivirus, Malware Bytes.

I'm desperate.

I need to track the process behind this script inclusion or a way to block it trough the browser.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Nah, that was for an specific line of script. I'm sure it bothers others. They will find this question one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it!

There was a process called `viva.exe`

I tracked down the folder where the exe was at, and closed the process. Then deleted the file.

The script is gone.